# Trying to call a function in my code, not working

Tags: swift

So I have created a function called startover1() and I am trying to call it in a different function, however, Xcode keeps saying there is an error.

I tried putting the function in different places, but it seems as though the function is not being read.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class BU: UIViewController {

    let allBUSentences = BUSentenceBank()
    var sentenceNumber2 : Int = 0


    @IBOutlet weak var BUSentenceLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let BUfirstQuestion = allBUSentences.list2[sentenceNumber2]
        BUSentenceLabel.text = BUfirstQuestion.BUSentenceText
    }


    @IBOutlet var BUNextButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func BUNext2(_ sender: Any) {

        sentenceNumber2 = sentenceNumber2 + 1
        nextSentence()


    }

    func nextSentence() {

        if sentenceNumber2 <= 19 {

            BUSentenceLabel.text = allBUSentences.list2[sentenceNumber2].BUSentenceText
        }
        else{

            let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Game Over", message: "Restart and keep drinking?", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let restartAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in self.startover1()

            }
            alert2.addAction(restartAction2)

            present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }            

        func startover1() {

            sentenceNumber2 = 0
            nextSentence()
        }           
    }

}
```

Hopefully it will recognize the method.  The error is Value of type 'BU' has no member 'startover1'

Comment: The method `startover1` is nested in `nextSentence`. Take it out.

Comment: Put it after or before `nextSentence()` instead of inside it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that nextSentence is nested inside another func declaration. To make it work simply remove the declaration to outside of the previous function scope defined by the {brackets}. Check out:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class BU: UIViewController {

let allBUSentences = BUSentenceBank()
var sentenceNumber2 : Int = 0


@IBOutlet weak var BUSentenceLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let BUfirstQuestion = allBUSentences.list2[sentenceNumber2]
    BUSentenceLabel.text = BUfirstQuestion.BUSentenceText
}


@IBOutlet var BUNextButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func BUNext2(_ sender: Any) {

    sentenceNumber2 = sentenceNumber2 + 1
    nextSentence()


}

func nextSentence() {

    if sentenceNumber2 <= 19 {

        BUSentenceLabel.text = allBUSentences.list2[sentenceNumber2].BUSentenceText
    }
    else{

        let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Game Over", message: "Restart and keep drinking?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let restartAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in self.startover1()

        }
        alert2.addAction(restartAction2)

        present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }            
    startover1() //This is not a declaration, but a call
}

//This is startover1 declaration
func startover1() {

    sentenceNumber2 = 0
    nextSentence()
}  

}
```